# Dynamic URLs for individual words in UILabel: Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsstring

I am trying to create a method that allows me to open a url based on the word clicked in a UILabel.

Currently, I am able to change the color the the words that start with a hashtag ("#").

```
// Change words that start with # to blue
NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", photoClass.description];
NSMutableAttributedString *attribString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:aString];
NSArray *words = [aString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
for (NSString *word in words){
    if ([word hasPrefix:@"#"]) {
        NSRange range = [aString rangeOfString:word];
        [attribString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[AnimatedMethods colorFromHexString:@"#47A8F2"] range:range];
   }
}
```

Is there a way to allow each changed word to open a url if a user clicks on the word?

For example, if I have the string `The #quick brown fox #jumped over the lazy dog`, I would like to open `url A` if `#quick` is selected and `url B` if `#jumped` is selected.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This might help https://github.com/Krelborn/KILabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me you can use this third party Library for your purpose

[KILabel](https://github.com/Krelborn/KILabel)
A simple to use drop in replacement for UILabel for iOS 7 and above that highlights links such as URLs, twitter style usernames and hashtags and makes them touchable.

[KILabel](https://github.com/Krelborn/KILabel) is available under the MIT license. So feel free to use

[image: KILabel]

I hope It may help you...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSLinkAttributeName`. Add the attribute the same way that you added the color. The value should be an `NSURL`.

i.e.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:@"your.url.com"];
[attribString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:url range:range];
```